# Using Android AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to create a single class which I can call when I need to show an AlertDialog with the parameters and son on I want.

The problem is I dont know if that class have to be an Activity... the alertDialog needs an context, but I can send the current one, because what I want is to show the alert on the actual activity (not to create a new one, I want to show the alert on the actual screen). But I cant get it. I get errors sending the context of the actual activity...

Only I get working it when I create that class like an Activity, but with that, the alertDialog appears alone without the actual screen behind.

What Can I do? I don't know if I understand the contexts...

Thanks

Comment: What code give you the error when sending the actual context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class does not need to extend anything to produce a dialog. You can try this way to produce a static method that creates a dialog for you. 
Make sure when you call your method you use THIS and not getApplicationContext()

```
MyDialogClass.getDialog(this); //good! 
MyDialogClass.getDialog(getApplicationContext()); //results in error
```

That is likely the cause of your error

Example class:

```
public class MyDialogClass
{
 public static AlertDialog getDialog(Context context)
    {
        Builder builder = new Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage("Msg").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {


                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really thanks! That is what I need! Also, I have another quick question: Can I get some data from string.xml outside of an activity? I get an error. Thanks again man :))

Comment: You should be able to as long as you have access to context somewhere by doing context.getString(R.string.your_resource);  If that's failing it may be because of what i said above where context is coming from getApplicationContext() instead of this. Could you tell us the error you are getting when you try to retrieve the value?

Comment: @dymmeh I didn't use any context. I thought the service of getting strings doesn't depends by the Activity... So, if it is only with Activitys, maybe I have to create another solution because I need to consult it with many non activity classes

Answer (score 0):

AynscTask does not need the `Context`; and no, it doesn't need to be an activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Anyways, you should be able to get the context anytime with no problems. Just do this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the context from wherever you want with `MyApplication.getAppContext();` and pass it on and it should work.